# PHP – check if request headers contain/is "'X-Requested-With': 'fetch'"

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, fetch

I really did some extensive research on stackoverflow and found many questions and answers, but still can't figure out what's wrong with the code snippet.

**Intend:**
Basically, I want to check if a request is made by the fetch API or not. If it's not I want PHP output only a small portion of the requested page. I am aware of the fetch API not sending any headers natively. However I'm using a fetch library which is successfully sending `'X-Requested-With': 'fetch'` (https://github.com/getdave/fetch-pjax). I am also aware of the possible header spoofing etc. It's a small website without any user credentials/cookies or similar.

**Code so far:**

```
  $headers = getallheaders(); 
  if(isset($headers['X-Requested-With']) && strtolower($headers['X-Requested-With']) == 'fetch') { 
    echo 'requested by the fetch API';
  } else {
    echo 'NOT requested by the fetch API';
  }
```

**Output:**
It's always echoing that it's not a fetch API call although according to the Chrome dev tools, the header `'X-Requested-With': 'fetch'` is sent. If I echo all the $headers, it's echoing all the headers of course. Could it be that there are also a couple of XHR-requests (not fetch API) from an animation plugin (*lottie.js*) made at the same time the fetch request is made (see screenshot below)?

[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What does `var_dump($headers);` show?

Comment: @JohnConde `array(14) {
  ["Host"]=>
  string(27) "example.com"
  ["Pragma"]=>
  string(8) "no-cache"
  ["Cache-Control"]=>
  string(8) "no-cache"
  ["X-Pjax"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["User-Agent"]=>
  string(121) "some browser list"
  ["Dnt"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["Accept"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["Sec-Fetch-Site"]=>
  string(11) "same-origin"
  ["Sec-Fetch-Mode"]=>
  string(4) "cors"
  ["Sec-Fetch-Dest"]=>
  string(5) "empty"
  ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
  string(17) "gzip, deflate, br"
  ["Accept-Language"]=>
  string(35) "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
}`

Comment: That header is clearly not sent. Are you sure chrome shows it being sent?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that they're missing, since I've not yet worked intensively with the fetch API I checked the wrong headers-tab in the dev-panel. I made a simple mistake in the fetch call in JavaScript. It works now! Thx again!

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a proper right answer to check because it was a kind of typo, so maybe this question can be deleted?